# NLog from different project

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm using more NLog instances within single project (see my previous question [Nlog config file priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894580/nlog-config-file-priority)). However, it doesn't work as expected.

If I call method that logs in second project, it's logged properly, but even after returning to previous project, items are being logged at wrong place.

So, for example Project1 has set to log in Project1.log, same way for second one. I can do method that simply calls:

```
Project1.Log.Write("1");
Project2.Log.Write("2");
Project1.Log.Write("3");
```

When I check logs, project1 contains "1", project 2 contains "2" and "3".

Exact (bit simplified) logger classes looks like:

```
public static class Log
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Logger> Logger = new Lazy<Logger>(CreateLogger);

    private static Logger CreateLogger()
    {
        string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(assemblyFolder + "\\ProjectX.exe.nlog", true); //X means project id
        return LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

    public static void Write(object log)
    {
        Logger.Value.Debug(log);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You modify static LogManager.Configuration that is single instance for entire process. see answer of Rolf Kristensen for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your previous question talks about the application should have priority in loading a single configuration for the entire application:

- Application-specific exe.nlog
- Fallback to global nlog.config

Now you are talking about having multiple assemblies in the same application, that wants to load their individual NLog-configuration side-by-side.

When using the static `LogManager.Configuration` then you are modifying the global configuration for the entire application. If two project-assemblies are changing the global configuration, then it will of course have side-effects for others.

Maybe your `CreateLogger` could look like this:

```
private static Logger CreateLogger()
{
    // Check for global NLog-configuration (Maybe your don't want this at all?)
    var configuration = LogManager.Configuration;
    if (configuration?.AllTarget.Count > 0)
        return LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    // Create assembly-specific NLog-configuration
    string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    LogFactory logFactory = new LogFactory();
    logFactory.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(assemblyFolder + "\\ProjectX.exe.nlog", true, logFactory); //X means project id
    return logFactory.GetCurrentClassLogger();
}
```

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-component-logging

Comment: Ha, many thanks to you, sir. I didn't realize that LogManager is static and expected it's instanced as you did in your example.